# API PLATFORM ApiTestCase authentication send unexpected response

Tags: symfony, authentication, testing, phpunit, api-platform.com

- Api platform version : 2.5.4
- PHPUnit version : 9.0.2
- Symfony version : 5.0.7

I made an API with API Platform. I handle security with a custom guard authenticator based on the symfony doc and a bearer JWT token. When I'm testing it manually with Postman, all is ok and works fine. When I'm testing it with the ApiTestCase class provided with API Platform, I got two kinds of error. They both happen in the same case :

- test 1 -> not authenticated -> response is ok
- test 2 -> authenticated -> response is ok
- test 3 -> authenticated or not -> response is wrong

When I am requesting a collection, the API only returns the first 2 or 3 elements and not all of them as it supposed to do.

When I am requestion an item, I simply got a 401 auth error.

Here is the code of my test class to reproduce the error :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase;

class MyCollectionTest extends ApiTestCase
{
    public function test1() #test is passing
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $response = $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            '/foos',
            [
                'headers'=> [],
                'json' => []
            ]
        );

        $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(200);
        $this->assertJsonEquals(['item1', 'item2', 'item3','item4', 'item5', 'item6']);
    }


    public function test2() #test is passing
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $response = $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            '/foos',
            [
                'headers'=> ['Authorization'=>'Bearer:valid_token'],
                'json' => []
            ]
        );

        $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(200);
        $this->assertJsonEquals(['item1', 'item2', 'item3','item4', 'item5', 'item6']);
    }

    public function test3() #test is invalid, only 'item1', 'item2', 'item3' are returned
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $response = $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            '/foos',
            [
                'headers'=> [],
                'json' => []
            ]
        );

        $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(200);
        $this->assertJsonEquals(['item1', 'item2', 'item3','item4', 'item5', 'item6']);
    }
}
?>
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase;

class MyItemTest extends ApiTestCase
{
    public function test1() #test is passing
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $response = $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            '/foos/1',
            [
                'headers'=> [],
                'json' => []
            ]
        );

        $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(200);
        $this->assertJsonEquals(['item1']);
    }


    public function test2() #test is passing
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $response = $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            '/foos/1',
            [
                'headers'=> ['Authorization'=>'Bearer:valid_token'],
                'json' => []
            ]
        );

        $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(200);
        $this->assertJsonEquals(['item1']);
    }

    public function test3() #test is invalid, 401 is returned
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $response = $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            '/foos/1',
            [
                'headers'=> [],
                'json' => []
            ]
        );

        $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(200);
        $this->assertJsonEquals(['item1']);
    }
}
?>
```

Any idea ? I already posted an issue on the Api Platform github last week but got no responses...

Comment: Your tests are perhaps good. It could be your application which have a problem. Could you provide us your security layers?

Comment: I made a github repo with my security setup so you can check it : https://github.com/deozza/stackoverflow-debug-apitestcase